# Why my file inside the folder is missing, but I can see it inside file explorer

Tags: asp.net

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

As u can see the productList file and be see outside of the ASP.sln file.
but when I click into the ASP.sln file, I can't found my productList.aspx file.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Project and click `Add -> Existing Item` now locate and add the file `ProductList.aspx`

It happens because project only recognise files as a part of project if the path to file exists in `.csproj` file. When we add the file by `Right click -> Add -> New Item` it makes an entry in `.csproj` file.

So, either use above method to add your file or you can make an entry of the file  in `.csproj` file